# Why doesn't MySQL use re-entrant locks?

Tags: mysql, transactions, deadlock

For my question, I refer to the deadlock example in the official docs at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlock-example.html.

I'm curious as to why the designers of MySQL chose not to allow locks to be re-entrant i.e. allow a transaction to use a lock it already holds skipping ahead of the queue.

In the example, when it says `Finally, client A also attempts to delete the row from the table:`, why can't A just skip the queue since it already holds the lock, and proceed to delete the row? Client B then runs its transaction, finds no row that matches `i=1` and succeeds. Couldn't a deadlock be avoided completely this way?

Comment: A read lock is not the same as a write lock and the difference usually ends up in some kind of optimization game. No matter what kind of scenario you can create, like the one in the example, where locks might be "solvable", there is an equal chance of creating a scenario that would break. Lock implementations in database engines tends to be conservative in implementation because no matter what you do, someone will always find a scenario where the lock implementation will do the wrong thing.

Comment: Basically what you're asking is "why isn't all read locks immediately escalated to a write lock because you may never know".

Comment: Why aren't read locks escalated to write locks _on demand_ though (like in the case above)? Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: KISS principle - keep it simple, stupid. Simpler rules are easier to implement, run faster, and the implementation is less likely to be buggy. In the particular example the onus should be on client 1 to request an exclusive lock in advsnce, if it knows it would like to  execute a delete later (or use serialisable isolation level...). But these are ust guesses. The answer to the why is: because the developers thought this is the best way to implement this feature. If you want to know the why, then you need to ask them.